# How to persist custom or non trivial data types in swi-prolog with persistency library?

Tags: persistence, swi-prolog

I want to persist my prolog database with peristency library (https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=persistency).

I have a module file with something like this:

```
:- module(model,
          [ campament/5
          ]).

:- use_module(library(persistency)).

:- persistent
   campament(name:atom, date_from:date, date_to:date, ubication:text, description:text).
```

This definition is related to `date` data type (https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=timedate), that is not present in error library (https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=error) mentioned in `persistent/1` (https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=persistent/1).

So, when I try to persist this clause I get an error:

```
?- use_module(model).

?- model:bd('data.db').

?- parse_time('20180720', iso_8601, From),
|  parse_time('20180729', iso_8601, To),
|  model:assert_campament('My campament', From, To, 'there', 'nothing').

ERROR: type `date' does not exist
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [15] throw(error(existence_error(type,date),_37572))
ERROR:   [11] model:assert_campament('My campament', From, To, 'there', 'nothing') at /home/xxx/model.pl:9
ERROR:    [9] <user>
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

How can I persist `date` like types? In `must_be/2` (https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=must_be/2), one of possible types is:

> ...
>
> `any` any term
>
> `type`    Term is a valid type specification
>
> ...

Regards.

Comment: I've made this question in swi-prolog forum too: https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/how-to-persist-custom-or-non-trivial-data-types-in-swi-prolog-with-persistency-library/4146/2 and a solution was provided.